# Insert is pasting in Waterfox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, manjaro

Pressing the insert key in Waterfox seems to paste the clipboard contents, as opposed to the usual behavior. Why is this? How can I change it?

Comment: Shift + Insert typically pastes from the clipboard. Are you also pressing Shift by chance?

Comment: @Peschke No, just insert. And it doesn't happen in Chromium, oddly enough.